# In the Soundcloud API, is information about a track still available after it's removed due to DMCA infringement?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm building an app that utilizes Soundcloud API and we came across a small problem. We archive playlists on our own servers to cut down on the amount of data needed to display tracks. So, for example, a user can create a playlist with tracks from soundcloud but we strip away the data provided by soundcloud to the minimum required to view and play said track. This data includes it's SC_ID, track name, artist, stream URL, etc. But doesn't provide the full data set SC does.

My question:

When songs are removed due to DMCA Copyright infringement, does SoundCloud keep the track ID and information available or does it remove the track entirely? What I mean by this is, say I have a track with ID 123456 and it was removed due to DMCA. Does this track still exist such that I could GET request [SC_api_url]/tracks/123456.json which would yield the track but it would not be streamable nor downloadable?

Correct my logic if I am wrong. I've searched the documentation and the best answer I can get is if you try and request a resource that is not available it throws a common 404 error but the API is not very clear on what happens when tracks are removed due to DMCA violations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I reached out to Soundcloud and they said that they are removed from the public facing API.

This means an error would occur if you referenced it.

This is also true for exceeding quotas.

Hope this also helps someone else too!